# Generating OAuth request token URL for OmniAuth

Tags: oauth, omniauth

I'm using OmniAuth to make OAuth and OAuth2 request token calls. I can successfully get the OAuth2 tokens but I'm finding it very difficult to work with OAuth. Specifically generating the URL to the providers request token endpoint. I've tried generating the URLs manually but the OAuth signature craziness blew my mind. I then tried to generate a URL with the OAuth gem but I can't seem to get it to spit out a URL. I can get it to return a token but that completely defeats the purpose of using OmniAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely missed the /auth/:provider portion of the OmniAuth gem.

OmniAuth automatically creates the /auth/:provider route in Rails. That will magically take you to whatever grant access page is necessary for the specified provider.